# Unknown layer type (crop) in Caffe for windows

Tags: python, caffe

I want to use the following convolutional neural network:

http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/

with caffe built from https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows

for windows 10 with visual studio 2013, CUDA 7.5, cudNN 4 and python support.

Now, when i call either of the two networks supplied with

```
net = caffe.Net('xyz.prototxt', 'xyz.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 43:85: Unknown enumeration value of "CROP" for field "type".
```

Line 43 of the network looks as follows:

```
layers { bottom: 'd3c' bottom: 'u3a' top: 'd3cc'  name: 'crop_d3c-d3cc'  type: CROP }
```

I have looked online and some people seem to encounter the same error message. I could not find any solutions, however.

My question now is: how do I get rid of this error?

Help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Changing the .prototxt as suggested by [Dale Song](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432128/6281477) eliminated this error, but led to another one:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 10:102: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "blobs_lr".
```

I fixed this by replacing

```
blobs_lr: 1 weight_decay: 1 blobs_lr: 2 weight_decay: 0
```

with

```
 param {lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1} param {lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0}
```

in the .prototxt, as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/kEJzMjNmO_M).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try changing "CROP" to "Crop".

Comment: I tried that. It gives the same error.

Comment: I did change layers { ...  type: CROP } to layer { ...  type: Crop } and layer { ...  type: "Crop" } but didn't work for me.

I didn't understand the second part of Dale Song's comment.

Can you please explain it more.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Message type "caffe.V1LayerParameter" has no field named "Crop". 

It seems, it has not been added in caffe yet, how did you manage it ? 

I have just installed Ubuntu 17 to install caffe for the same reason. Though, couldn't solved the issue. PS: I am also working on the same code.

Comment: Don't know, what I did but now it is showing the following error which is same  I faced when working on Windows:


`Expected integer or identifier, got: "Crop'"`


Here is my code
`layers { bottom: 'd3c' bottom: 'u3a' top: 'd3cc'  name: 'Crop_d3c-d3cc'  type: "Crop" }`

Comment: Change layers to layer. that should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

You should modify `net.prototxt` from:

`layers { ...  type: CROP }` to

`layer { ...  type: "Crop" }`

and meanwhile, other layers' parameter in the prototxt should also be modified similarly to:

`layer { ... type: "TypeString" }`,

and the `TypeString` can be found from:

1. The line `REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(some_layer_name)` in related `some_layer_name_layer.cpp` file. For example, `REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(Data)` in `data_layer.cpp` means the `TypeString` should be `Data` when writing a data layer in `net.prototxt`.
2. `REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(some_layer_name, GetSomeLayer)` in `layer_factory.cpp`. For example, `REGISTER_LAYER_CREATOR(Convolution, GetConvolutionLayer)` means the `TypeString` should be `Convolution` when writing a convolution layer in `net.prototxt`.

**Reason:**

The reason for your problem is: you used an old layer parameter format

`layers { ...  type: SOMELAYERNAME }`.

and this format coming from `V1LayerParameter` in [caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/windows/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) doesn't support some newer layer type including the `crop` layer.

You can confirm this by checking that `enum LayerType` of `V1LayerParameter`  doesn't include layer type `CROP`.

To avoid this probelm, you can always use the newest format:

`layer { ... type: "TypeString" }`

in which the `TypeString` can be found in the 2 places mentioned above.

---

**Edit 1**

**A simple remark:**

In general, the error:

```
Error parsing text-format caffe.xxxParameter: ...
```

can always be solved by checking that the `xxx.prototxt` files use the right field names declared in [**caffe.proto**](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/windows/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) and right values are assigned to them(by checking the field type and its value range).