# error when using pycaffe

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm running a python file with `pycaffe`. And it gives a error like below. Can somebody help me to slove this problem?

> ```
> W1102 08:58:27.428354  1521 _caffe.cpp:125] DEPRECATION WARNING - deprecated use of Python interface
> W1102 08:58:27.428395  1521 _caffe.cpp:126] Use this instead (with the named "weights" parameter):
> W1102 08:58:27.428400  1521 _caffe.cpp:128] Net('/home/medha/videosynthesis/Models/c3d_sport1m_feature_extractor_frm_edit.prototxt', 1, weights='/home/medha/videosynthesis/Models/conv3d_deepnetA_sport1m_iter_1900000')
> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter:10:3: Unknown enumeration value of "VIDEO_DATA" for field "type".
> F1102 08:58:27.431226  1521 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /home/medha/videosynthesis/Models/c3d_sport1m_feature_extractor_frm_edit.prototxt
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

Comment: The error indicates that the old layer type `VIDEO_DATA` is not supported by the caffe you used. You should check whether it has a layer such as `video_data_layer.cpp` in it. If it has such a layer and you still get this error, then you can refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/39432128/6281477.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do video classification using [C3D caffe](https://github.com/facebook/C3D).
From the title of C#D github page you can see that

> C3D is a modified version of BVLC caffe

One modification made is adding `VIDEO_DATA` layer.

Please pull the latest version from C3D caffe, install it and use it for your experiments. Do **not** use regular caffe - it will not work.