# pycaffe does not recognise a valid parameter in prototxt file

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I'm trying to understand what the convolutional neural network [SegNet](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html) does, so I created a Python module to lad it, hoping to print out the different shapes and properties of its layers.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import caffe

caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/models/segnet_train.prototxt', caffe.TEST)

[print(k, v.data.shape) for k, v in net.blobs.items()]
```

But it tells me that the file is incorrect, although I can correctly train this net with SegNet provided files (see the prototxt file [here](http://piratepad.net/JgFNf9kQ1U)). What does this mean and what should I do?

Here is the full error

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 7:26: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "dense_image_data_param".
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F1212 15:59:09.624486 20202 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /path/to/models/segnet_train.prototxt
```

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/a/39432128/6281477 may provide you some hint.

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly my error though. I've got nothing of this kind to modify yet, so I've changed _dense\_image\_data\_param_ to _image\_data\_param_. Now the error has changed to `... has no parameter "bn_param"`. I've found somthing [here](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/issues/13) but I don't understand it. Can you help me?

Comment: I guess you didn't install the right version of caffe that SegNet requres. Because different version of caffe may have different `caffe.proto` and different layers within folder `src/caffe/layers/`.

Comment: And make sure your `pycaffe` is built from the right version of caffe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dale pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104549/pycaffe-does-not-recognise-a-valid-parameter-in-prototxt-file?noredirect=1#comment69439069_41104549), it was indeed a caffe version problem. I did use an independent caffe build, whereas SegNet comes with its own caffe.

I changed the python path to this distribution, and everything worked fine.